# Loading Google Analytics Chart Returns Bad Request

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, google-analytics-api, bad-request

In my application i displayed google analytics in charts.This is the link where i downloaded the analytics api:
http://mikhailkozlov.com/how-to-show-analytics-data-with-google-chart-tools/

This is the code:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/chart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#chart").drawChart({uri:'<?php echo base_url();?>js/_ga.php'});
</script>
```

Html code:

```
<div id="chart" style="height:300px; width:940px; padding:0; color:#258cd1" class="visits bars last_30"></div>
```

When this loading chart get an error in fire bug:

```
"NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bvs&chxt=y,x&chbh=a,5,10&chs=0x0&chco=258cd1&chg=0,10,0,0&chts=676767,11&chds=0,25&chxr=0,0,25|1,0,31&chd=t:0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,5,3,2,15,0,2,7,12,0,11,12,0,8,8,3,4,7,2,0,10,3,0&chxl=1:|08|09|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31|01|02|03|04|05|06|07"
```

Comment: Is your goal to show Analytics data specific to each user, or do you want to show all users the same Analytics data?

Answer (score 0):

It may be because Google has changed the way it authorizes requests and the data it returns. Detail on [this post](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2011/12/introducing-google-analytics-core.htmlhttp://analytics.blogspot.com/2012/01/update-on-new-version-of-google.html) and [this post](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2012/01/update-on-new-version-of-google.html). Also, [What Is The Core Reporting API - Overview](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/v2/gdataOverview.html)  has more info.

Note also that the way this app authorizes is with ClientLogin (email, password). That is a security risk on a web app; it should only be used on an installed local app.

You can now use a refresh token to access GA data.

See [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) and then add the charting.

So until this code is updated, you may have to find another method to build your charts. You may be able to use [Google Analytics Core Reporting API (Data Export) with Google Chart Visualizations](http://www.jensbits.com/2010/06/23/google-analytics-data-export-api-with-google-chart-visualizations-2/)